# Creating a SQL Table and passing a python function

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, amazon-redshift, etl

I need to create a SQL table but I need to add a column where in which I pass a python function. Ultimately what this python does it takes all the values from an `email` column and cleans it up i.e. trim and etc. this function is called  `clean_email`

So far I have my data frame in a Jupyter notebook my table looks like this

```
df = pd.read_sql("""select id, 
                     user_id,
                     is_gift,
                     date_trunc('day',
                         created_at AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern') 
                         as created_at,
                         product_line,
                         email
                         from (select s.*, 
                               u.email,
                               row_number() over (
                               partition by user_id 
                               order by s.created_at asc) rn
                                    from table1 s
                                    inner join table2 u on s.user_id = u.id) 
                            where rn = 1 
                            order by created_at desc """,
                              conn)
```

and I added a column to this dataframe using pandas like such:

```
df['clean_email'] = df['email'].apply(clean_email)
```

My question is: I know how to manipulate dataframes using Pandas but how do I do this so I can create this same DataFrame as a table in my Redshift schema for ETL purposes?

Comment: do you know about `pd.read_sql`? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html

Comment: Yes but that is not my issue, I can read sql no problem, I just didnt specify that method in my question sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

You can now take the same dataframe and push it back to redshift.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgres://%s:%s@%s:8192/<db>' %(username, dbpassword, dbhost), encoding="utf-8")

DF.to_sql('<table name>', engine, schema='<insert schema>', if_exists='<replace or append>', index=<True or False>)
```

Comment: Yes, actually you're probably right it needs to be called out specifically.  I assumed he knew how to make it.

Comment: I tried this and for some reason it was taking forever. Also, I noticed that it was indeed doing something as I saw the table and the schema in my database but when I queryed from there I saw no data inside the table. What could be the issue?

Comment: be sure the table you are inserting to has the structure you need. it may crash if you have added a column which did not previously exist.

Comment: This would be a new table that never previously existed. The tables and columns are being created but there is no data being populated inside of it.

Comment: The length of time is really dependent on the amount of data, especially with redshift.